# changing the names of app once it is approved by apple

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im little bit confused with a issue.

I have submitted the two versions of my app.

Both versions are approved by apple.

When i submitted unfortunately i gave the names in wrong way,for full version i gave(sample full) and lite version as (sample)

Now my client what the full version to be read as (sample) and lite version as (sample lite).

When i changed the bundle name it is showing in the way i want (below icon).

But in itunes when submitting both are showing (sample).

will this be an issue.?

how can i change the name in itunes connect while submitting the update.?

Can anyone help me please.

thanks in advance.

Comment: unfortunately, you can't. check again, it would be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the name of the app that will be displayed into iTunes. you can change the bundle name, you can change many things around this, but not the name that appear near the icon of the app into iTunes, except sending a request to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you currently have:

- Version A's name = (sample full)
- Version B's name = (sample)

And you want:

- Version A's name = (sample)
- Version B's name = (sample lite)

It is possible to change an app's name when you create a new version in iTunes Connect but you can't choose a name that is already in existence. So in this case you'll first need to update version B and renaming it (sample lite), wait until approval is complete, and only then, now that (sample) is no longer in use, update version A and renaming it (sample) and wait until approval is complete.